# How can I get glmer model to read "missing" data as zeros?

Tags: r, glm, lme4

I have data that is missing values, how can I get a glmer model to read these as 0's so i can avoid this... I know that I have less observations than random effects, I just don't understand R well enough to fix it.

This is the data i am trying to run the model on.

```
> dput(as.data.frame(wi.age.count))
structure(list(Year = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2007", "2007", 
"2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018"), Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), n = c(166, 
28, 34, 77, 170, 18, 3, 22, 43, 50, 151, 1, 8, 17, 1, 4, 19, 
1, 1, 46, 37, 52, 5, 1, 1, 19, 41, 15, 16, 1, 1, 13, 4, 26, 12, 
11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 87, 15, 13, 27, 13, 17, 1, 1, 32, 30, 3, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 24, 15, 23, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 18, 13, 31, 28, 3, 3, 
6, 1, 4, 6, 1, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 16, 16, 8, 1, 1, 4, 1, 12, 4, 7, 
2, 1, 2, 1), id = c("YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", 
"YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult"), Cohort = c("2008", "2009", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2007", "2006", "2005", "2002", "2007", "2006", "2005", 
"2009", "2008", "2007", "2006", "2005", "2004", "2003", "2009", 
"2008", "2007", "2006", "2001", "2011", "2010", "2009", "2008", 
"2007", "2006", "2005", "2004", "2003", "2012", "2011", "2010", 
"2009", "2008", "2007", "2006", "2005", "2013", "2012", "2011", 
"2010", "2009", "2008", "2007", "2006", "2014", "2013", "2012", 
"2011", "2010", "2009", "2008", "2007", "2006", "2015", "2014", 
"2013", "2012", "2011", "2010", "2009", "2008", "2006", "2015", 
"2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2010", "2007", "2017", "2016", 
"2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2018", "2017", "2016", 
"2015", "2014", "2013", "2012", "2011")), row.names = c(NA, -95L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The data looks like this, except the model needs values where they are "missing". They are not really missing they should be zeros. Is there a way to add these into my data frame?
[image: The data looks like this, except the model needs values where they are "missing"]

This is the model I am trying to run.

```
> glmer(n~ Age + (1|Cohort) + (Age|Year), data=wi.age.count, subset=as.numeric(as.character(Cohort))>2005, family=poisson)
Error: number of observations (=84) < number of random effects (=120) for term (Age | Year); the random-effects parameters are probably unidentifiable
```

Comment: Convert missing values to zeros before running the model: `wi.age.count$Age[is.na(wi.age.count$Age)] = 0`

Comment: It appears to me that `Age` is a factor with 10 levels, thus you end up with many small cells in which the sample size is too small to calculate coefficients.  I don't see any missing values in our data.

Comment: You're proposing to convert your data to fit your model.  This is a bad thing to do.  You should adjust your model to fit your data.  And I agree with @ZhiqiangWang: your model is too complex for your data.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to get this or a similar model to run?